# Combining intra and inter cohort comparison using panel-data

Tags: panel-data, group-differences, difference-in-difference, case-cohort

After reading numerous posts, I still haven't found a conclusive answer to my question. I have panel data for the whole population(multiple years, interlinked by personal identification numbers), containing data for i.a. age, wage, study area, university where the degree is attained, sector of employment, place of residence etc.

My presumption is that (when controlling for study program and cost of living) the wage patterns for people from University A, developed over time different from the people that attained their degree from University B, due to characteristics of the local labour market in question. The inserted picture below gives an illustration of the dynamics observed in the data (numbers are fictitious). We can clearly see that University A(depicted by the blue dots and lines) is starting in both the 1980 and 1990 cohort with a higher wage, but that University B( in Red/Orange) is able to catch up or even achieve a higher wage.

Although I am able to show it in this manner, I am looking for a proper statistical technique for this analysis. I have read numerous post and scientific papers on related topics, but still didn't found a conclusive answer. To give some additional clarification to my question:

- Do I need to do an difference in difference analysis per cohort?
- How can I compare the difference between the cohorts in the DID? (I want to be able to say that the 1990 cohort of University A is facing worse relative labour market conditions then the 1980 cohort of University A.

I hope that the community can give me some advice on this. Please let me know when I need to add more information.

[image]